# How to access value from a MAP in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Hi I have a following lightning component code.

============My Component =============
[image]

======================================

The map 'myMap' is loaded with some data through the controller.
Im not getting how will I access the value from the map "myMap" inside the component.

I dont want to iterate over the map
Just need to access a value from It something like myMap.get('Key1') inside the component;

=========MyComponentController==========

[image]

============================

==========MyClass=============

```
public with sharing class MyClass

{
      public static Map<String,String> getMap()

      {
            Map<String,String> map = new Map<String,String>();
          map.put('key1','value1');
          map.put('key2','value2');
          return map;

      }

}
```

Comment: try writing `{!v.myMap[keyName]}`;

Comment: Didn't Worked.
I tried with {!v.myMap.keyName}. This is working but only if we hardcode the keyName. 
I want to use the key name Dynamically through some vairable.

Comment: Please include your code as text, *not* images. It is horrible user experience for the community members trying to help you.